# In golang what is the type of name in ec2.CreateSecurityGroup

Tags: go, goamz

I am using CreateSecurityGroup func in golang using goamz.
Below is the function signature:

```
func (ec2 *EC2) CreateSecurityGroup(name, description string) (resp *CreateSecurityGroupResp, err error)
```

What type does the argument `name` have in this argument list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec for [function of method signature](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Signature) allows for parameters to use an [`IdentifierList` for one type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#IdentifierList):

```
ParameterDecl  = [ IdentifierList ] [ "..." ] Type .
```

- `name, description` is the identifier list.
- `string` is the type which applies to that list.

You have the same feature for [variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations):

```
var U, V, W float64
```

All three variables have the same type `float64`.

---

Note: a more recent version of the goamz source code shows that same method with a different parameter: see [commit 04a8dd3](https://github.com/mitchellh/goamz/commit/04a8dd36910252affbb4c0ea59b1d3c898d5c255)

```
func (ec2 *EC2) CreateSecurityGroup(group SecurityGroup)
  (resp *CreateSecurityGroupResp, err error) {...
```

with:

```
type SecurityGroup struct {
    Id string `xml:"groupId"`   + Id string `xml:"groupId"`
    Name string `xml:"groupName"`   + Name string `xml:"groupName"`
    Description string `xml:"groupDescription"`
    VpcId string `xml:"vpcId"`
}
```

This is typical when the number of potential parameters grows: you wrap them in a struct.

It is used in [this test](https://github.com/mitchellh/goamz/blob/835bb759f66f80805f855201eb6bc6243b059a65/ec2/ec2_test.go#L728):

```
resp, err := 
  s.ec2.CreateSecurityGroup(ec2.SecurityGroup{Name: "websrv", 
                                              Description: "Web Servers"})
```

Comment: This gives context to the question. I wasn't sure what the OP was asking. Will update the question +1